# PowerShell - actions over files in folders and subfolders

Tags: powershell, uipath

So basically, there is a tab in a website containing thousands of .pdf files. It's a list with folders of which some of them have subfolders. Obviously, these folders/subfolders contain the files. In order to download the files, I need to open each and every folder, right click on every single file and click download. Is there a way to automate this recursively with PowerShell for all the files? Or maybe UiPath?

Comment: Can you show that website?

Comment: Is it by chance the directory listing of a webserver that you are seeing?

Comment: @kwoxer I'm not allowed to. It's ministry's private files that only me and a few other colleagues have access to (through the website). Imagine it as a list with expandable folders/subfolders/.../

Comment: @ManuelBatsching No. Long story short, I login on that website, i search a project by a code, and then it returns all the uploaded documents related to that project. Those projects are categorised in many different folders/subfolders (all expandable). I need to download all files from all existing projects because we are trying to migrate to a different db. I need something automated so I don't have to manually download tens of thousands of files.

Comment: You could use a browser automation like selenium to automatically enter the project codes and then scrape the corresponding site for download links. But that will be very cumbersome. Can`t you talk to the current provider, if they can export the files for you or provide you with limited shell access to the server, which holds the pdf files?

Comment: I would use the Scraping Tool of UiPath. But maybe you could also connect via SFTP? Another solution would be Selenium. Or even using a Browser Plugin. Plenty of solutions. But all depends on how the website looks like and if it's a website directory or a custom one.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Getting access to the storage server was my first try, but they wont give us access. Guess ill try with either selenium or uipath. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How the website looks like? Is it similar to e.g. [Index of /Public/UNIDATA](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/)? Then you could utilize  `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SourceURL).Links` (where `$SourceURL` is the url of folder to copy).…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to access the server files directly, so not through the website but through Windows Explorer then that would probably rule out, or at least make it quite trick to use power shell.

However this is something that UiPath should be able to cope with quite easily. Several automation's I have worked on do a similar thing.

Essentially the automation would need to do the following

- login
- enter search terms
- for each returned folder

  - for each file in folder

    - Download file
  - for each folder in folder

    - repeat above

Essentially you need to build a recursive loop to loop through all of the folders and files, downloading a file when you encounter one

Comment: Could you provide an e-mail to keep in touch? I'm new to UiPath. Still going through tutorial.

Comment: Are you on the UiPath forum. Feel free to message me through there, https://forum.uipath.com/u/conorsmalley

Comment: I can't see a chat option in that forum. I added you on facebook though.